# cURL - how to send HTTP Request message body with GET?

Tags: http, curl

Why there is no request message body when we use GET with cURL? For example:

```
curl -G http://0.0.0.0:8181 -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
```

Result:

```
== Info: Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55c11868f5c0)
== Info:   Trying 0.0.0.0...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55c11868f5c0)
== Info: Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 8181 (#0)
=> Send header, 104 bytes (0x68)
0000: GET /?param1=value1&param2=value2 HTTP/1.1
002c: Host: 0.0.0.0:8181
0040: User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
0059: Accept: */*
0066:

<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 20 bytes (0x14)
0000: Host: 0.0.0.0:8181
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Thu, 19 Sep 2019 00:34:38 GMT
<= Recv header, 19 bytes (0x13)
0000: Connection: close
<= Recv header, 56 bytes (0x38)
0000: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.9-1+ubuntu19.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000:
<= Recv data, 56 bytes (0x38)
0000: Array.(.    [param1] => value1.    [param2] => value2.).
Array
(
    [param1] => value1
    [param2] => value2
)
== Info: Closing connection 0
```

I can see the message body with POST, for example:

```
curl http://0.0.0.0:8181 -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" --trace-ascii /dev/stdout
```

Result:

```
== Info: Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55b4a43355c0)
== Info:   Trying 0.0.0.0...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55b4a43355c0)
== Info: Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 8181 (#0)
=> Send header, 146 bytes (0x92)
0000: POST / HTTP/1.1
0011: Host: 0.0.0.0:8181
0025: User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
003e: Accept: */*
004b: Content-Length: 27
005f: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
0090:
=> Send data, 27 bytes (0x1b)
0000: param1=value1&param2=value2
== Info: upload completely sent off: 27 out of 27 bytes

<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 20 bytes (0x14)
0000: Host: 0.0.0.0:8181
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Fri, 20 Sep 2019 03:12:32 GMT
<= Recv header, 19 bytes (0x13)
0000: Connection: close
<= Recv header, 56 bytes (0x38)
0000: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.9-1+ubuntu19.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000:
<= Recv data, 56 bytes (0x38)
0000: Array.(.    [param1] => value1.    [param2] => value2.).
Array
(
    [param1] => value1
    [param2] => value2
)
== Info: Closing connection 0
```

As you can see the message body in the POST method above:

```
=> Send data, 27 bytes (0x1b)
0000: param1=value1&param2=value2
== Info: upload completely sent off: 27 out of 27 bytes
```

But there is none in the GET method. How do we display the message body with the GET message?

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

```
$ curl http://0.0.0.0:8181 -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" --trace-ascii - -X GET
== Info: Expire in 0 ms for 6 (transfer 0x55bf2e32d5c0)
== Info:   Trying 0.0.0.0...
== Info: TCP_NODELAY set
== Info: Expire in 200 ms for 4 (transfer 0x55bf2e32d5c0)
== Info: Connected to 0.0.0.0 (127.0.0.1) port 8181 (#0)
=> Send header, 145 bytes (0x91)
0000: GET / HTTP/1.1
0010: Host: 0.0.0.0:8181
0024: User-Agent: curl/7.64.0
003d: Accept: */*
004a: Content-Length: 27
005e: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
008f: 
=> Send data, 27 bytes (0x1b)
0000: param1=value1&param2=value2
== Info: upload completely sent off: 27 out of 27 bytes
<= Recv header, 17 bytes (0x11)
0000: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<= Recv header, 20 bytes (0x14)
0000: Host: 0.0.0.0:8181
<= Recv header, 37 bytes (0x25)
0000: Date: Fri, 20 Sep 2019 15:07:34 GMT
<= Recv header, 19 bytes (0x13)
0000: Connection: close
<= Recv header, 56 bytes (0x38)
0000: X-Powered-By: PHP/7.3.9-1+ubuntu19.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
<= Recv header, 40 bytes (0x28)
0000: Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
<= Recv header, 2 bytes (0x2)
0000: 
<= Recv data, 10 bytes (0xa)
0000: Array.(.).
Array
(
)
== Info: Closing connection 0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because with `-G` you asked curl to convert the `-d` data and put it in the URL query instead.

To fix, remove `-G`, keep `-d` but enforce `GET` with `-X`:

```
curl http://0.0.0.0:8181 -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" --trace-ascii - -X GET
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but the data `"param1=value1&param2=value2"` are not sent at all. see mu edit above

Comment: Look again? 
`=> Send data, 27 bytes (0x1b)
0000: param1=value1&param2=value2`

Comment: sorry i mean in the response, the array is empty `0000: Array.(.).`

Comment: also in the request,  `0000: GET / HTTP/1.1` should be `0000: GET /?param1=value1&param2=value2 HTTP/1.1`

Comment: you are sending a post data actually, you can see what it says at this line `005e: Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`

Comment: You've lost me. I thought you were doing a GET with a request body. What exactly do you want the request to do?

Comment: If you want `GET /?param1=value1&param2=value2` then add that to the URL you ask for: `http://example.com/?param1=value1&param2=value2`

Comment: The array is what you received back from the server (`<= Recv data`), so now your problem is on the server.
Note that the http protocol says that GET doesn't have a body, and many server implementations ignore it.